# Word 365 Markup/final view UI display problems

Tags: vba, view, ms-word, markup

Because of lockdown measures, I've recently begun working from home. I work for an editing company, and I'm required to do a lot of reviewing of editor work (in addition to editing, re-editing). This requires me to quickly and frequently toggle between markup (tracked changes) view and final view. I have hotkey macros to do this, but unlike my 2016 version at my office, Word 365 does not retain the current position when I toggle views, but instead it (the display) jumps to the same page on the other view (the cursor does remain), making it so I lose my place and have to spend seconds finding it again. I *need* to be able to quickly toggle while keeping my eyes fixed on the current cursor position. I've adjusted my macro so it still keeps the cursor on the page, but it nevertheless jumps around within the page. I need the cursor and its displayed position on the page to remain fixed when switching views.

A secondary problem related to this is that when I select words in final view to comment on (or to edit/replace/highlight/etc.), these words are not actually selected as it jumps to markup view (instead seemingly just selecting the one single next word).

This may not be the appropriate place for a question like this, but I didn't know if some finagling with VBA might help me out here or maybe there were just some people with more Office expertise.

Thanks for any help!

Here is my macro. It's extremely basic, and I just did it from "record macro"; I've done very little actual VBA coding. I believe this is equivalent to clicking "all markup" and then pressing CTRL+RightArrow. The ones to show the final and original text are the same except for the .markUp.

Ideally, I wouldn't need any code because it would just be some setting I'm not aware of, but I know they love to change the fundamentals of how staple programs like Word operate between versions just to mess with people.

```
Sub markUp()
'
' markUp Macro
'
'
    With ActiveWindow.View.RevisionsFilter
        .markUp = wdRevisionsMarkupAll
        .View = wdRevisionsViewFinal
    End With
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the code of your existing macro.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.